# Converting String to bit before inserting into the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

Can anyone help in converting string value in C# to bit equivalent in Sql.  I'm trying to bulkcopy the values of a datatable into Sql table.  All the values I've in the datatable are in string format.  When I try to bulkcopy to SQL table I'm getting an error for bit datatype columns.Can anyone please post the C# code to convert string to bit type before I bulkcopy to SQL table.

Thanks,
Vix

Answer (score 5):

If your strings are "true" and "false" (ignoring case and whitespace) this will work:

```
bool bit = bool.Parse(str);
```

If your strings are something else, you could use:

```
bool bit = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) &&
  (str[0]=='Y' || str[0]=='y' || str[0]=='T' || str[0]=='t' || str[0]=='1');
```

SQL wants a bool value.

Comment: Thanks Ray.How do I convert string to float for the same scenario.I tried Convert.ToDouble(str); but it didn't work.Please help.

Comment: I use double.Parse() for the 'float' SQL data type, but Convert.ToDouble() just calls double.Parse() so it should have worked.   Did the Convert.ToDouble() call itself throw an exception, or did SQL reject the resulting value?  Also, what data access layer are you using (ie. what calls are you using to submit your data?)

Comment: Ray,When I try to bulkcopy the values of datatable which already has the cell after Convert.ToDouble(str) I'm getting the following error.


System.InvalidOperationException: The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type float of the specified target column. ---> System.FormatException: Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Double. ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)

Comment: when I call this method bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dtUpdate); to copy values from datatable to Sql table,I'm getting the error.But when I see the value in the datatable for which it throws the exception it's a valid number.All the values for the column are valid numbers.

Comment: The exception you are quoting would happen if the value in dtUpdate is a string and can't be parsed.  Some possiblities:  Column.DataType is not Double, Column names or order mixed up.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server will recognise ["true" and "false" for the bit datatype](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx). Also, zero stores zero, non-zero stores as "1".

Are you sending `"true"` or `true`?

If you get the same error with doubles (as per comments to other answers), then I suspect you are sending quotes.

Answer (score 1):

```
int a = Convert.ToInt32( row.ItemArray[5]);
bool b;
b = Convert.ToBoolean(a);
switch (a)
{
    case 1:
        b = true;
        break;
    case 0:
        b = false;
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `bit` data type in SQL Server matches up to the `bool` data type in C#.  So just convert your strings to `bool`s (using [`bool.Parse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.parse.aspx) or your favorite alternative) and you should be set.

Comment: Thanks,Daniel.How do I convert string to float for the same scenario.I tried using Convert.ToDouble(str); but it didn't work.Please help